# Phonology of “gg” + “i”

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

I read that “gg” is a geminated or lengthened consonant. I have also read that before “i”, “g” is made into the affricate. So, should I make “ggi” into a geminated affricate?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Thank you I have 1 friend who is an Italian / filipino who invited me to learn it -

Comment: Could you give an example of a word whose pronunciation you would like to understand? From what I can tell the answer to your questions is "yes", but pronunciation is always so tricky and context depending that concrete examples will make it easier for us to write an answer.

Comment: Like in messaggio

Comment: Is your question about terminology (i.e., if “geminated affricate” is the correct term) or about how to pronounce such letters? In any case, there is an apparently in-depth study on the matter here: http://newyork.diet.uniroma1.it/Papers/J16-Faluschi_al-EJLS01.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Italian the letters *gi* may form a digraph that denotes the affricate pronunciation /d͡ʒ/ before *a*, *o* or *u*. Before *e* or *i*, the consonant *g* is pronounced /d͡ʒ/. In all the following words, there is the affricate:

*giacca gioco giusto gente ginestra*

To be clearer, *gi* is a digraph only if another vowel (*a*, *o* or *u*) follows. However, it is not a digraph if the *i* is tonic (like in *pubalgia* or *leggii*, plural of *leggio*).

In the first three words there is *no* /i/ sound.

When the affricate is geminated, it is written *gg* (before *e* or *i*) or *ggi* (before *a*, *o* or *u*):

*roggia messaggio laggiù aggettivo raggi*

The surface pronunciation of the affricate /d͡ʒ/ may vary depending on the speaker’s variety of Italian, in particular for the geminated one that can even become very similar to /j/; pronouncing /d͡ʒ/ as [ʒ] is not at all uncommon in central Italy (some parts of Tuscany, for instance). In southern Italy, /d͡ʒ/ is commonly geminated also when standard Italian would prescribe no gemination.

Comment: Does that mean that ginestra is pronounced as /d͡ʒ/nestra - -

Comment: @LolFlo No, the /i/ is pronounced; `gi` is a digraph only if another vowel (a, o or u) follows. I added some clarifications.